# Would it be safe to fill the gap between the engineered hardwood and an integral metal door jamb?

Tags: flooring

As part of a renovation, I had new engineered hardwood flooring installed in most of my apartment. They installed skirting board to cover almost all gaps between the wall and the floor, but there are a few places where they decided not to do that.

In particular, the door jambs in my apartment are metal and plastered into the walls they sit in. So there are these annoying and unsightly gaps between the door jambs and the flooring.

[image]

At some point I'm planning to sand and repaint the doors and door trims. Would it be safe to use a flexible caulking (or similar) to fill the gap along the floor, and then perhaps paint that when I repaint the doors and door trims?

Comment: This is an apartment that you own and rent out?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that The door frames will be painted in the future, (if the future is not too far away),  I would wait, paint the frames then fill in the gaps in the floor with a flexible caulk close to the color of the floor.

So; Would it be safe?  Yes